# How to ignore faces permanently in iPhoto?

Tags: macos, photos.app

How to tell iPhoto to ignore the specific faces permanently if I want to ignore them. When I click close button it doesn't work, because the next time when I find faces, THE SAME faces appear again and again.

Anyone knows how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 1):

When you click on "search faces", you will be presented with groups of four faces. Hover with the mouse over the picture of a face, and a small circle with an "x" will appear in the top left corner. When you select this x, this face will never pop up again.

But you have to do this for every instance of that face. If you have hundreds of images with one particular person which you will not add to your known faces, you will need to click on every instance of it.

Comment: what does it mean for every instance of that face? Why do i have to click 'x' a few times before it disappear permanently?

Comment: @BartłomiejSemańczyk: If the face is in more than one picture, iPhoto has no way to disable all instances of that face with one click. You need to click the "x" for every occurrence of the face separately.

Answer (score 1):

One way I've gotten around this is to "name" any people that I want to ignore with "anonymous", or "X", so that I can quickly put them in that category using the keyboard only and they will not show up every time I find faces. It would be great if there was a better way!